# How to set variable to the text of a particular page element using jQuery/Coffeescript?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to use Coffeescrip/jQuery to iterate through every span on a page and return the text enclosed between a particular span's tags if the id of that span is equal to the variable `elemId`. Here's what I have:

```
elemValue = $('span').each ->
  $(@).text() if $(@).attr("id") is elemId
```

For some reason, though, this only returns `[object Object]` for the `elemValue` that I output to the page, even when I test it on a page that I know has a span with that `elemId`. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Also, how to set a default value for `elemValue`, in case there is no span on the page has an id that is the same as `elemId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you know the id then why are you iterating whole span. just use id to get text

```
 $("#" +elemId ).text()
```

Comment: Or `$("##{elemId}").text()` since this is CoffeeScript.

Comment: Yup, that solves it. I'm not sure why I was trying to do it in such a complex way: guess I need more sleep.

What's the easiest way to set a default value for the elemValue variable in Coffeescript, in case there is no span with that id on the page?

Comment: @Michael: something like `t = $("##{elemId}").text() || 'pancakes'` would probably do but I'd check if `$("##{elemId}").length` was zero because I'm paranoid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what should work for you, and makes a whole lot more sense:

```
$('#' + elemId).each(function () {
   console.log('$(this).text());
});
```

To set default value, here's what you need to do:

```
if (document.indexOf(elemId) < 0) {
    var elemValue = "whatever you want"
}
```